# Возможно ли мониторить загруженность диска виртуальной машины

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, hyper-v, windows-server-2008

Возможно ли следить активностью, загруженностью диска виртуальной машины ? (VirtualBox,VMWare + Windows server 2008)
По сути виртуалка у нас локально в файле хранится же, и как будет виртуалка показывать скорость записи, активность ? Вообще покажет ли или все время будет сымитировать что нет нагрузки на HDD(виртуалки) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на виртуалке запустить программу мониторинга активности, она будет видеть только ту нагрузку на диск, что создают программы внутри виртуалки.

Нагрузку на диск от программ на хостовой системе и от других виртуалок видно не будет.